# Send_transaction function is it used?

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code

I found a strange function(send_transaction) in eos.

The function is used in 1.7 version. But It looks like doesn't used in 1.8 version. And the function is duplicated of the push_transaction.

Finally, It seems to be deprecated. But why the function changed name and still set the function in chain_api_plugin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions do the same thing but there's a small difference in the response from them. The developers are careful with backwards compatibility and this is why the new function was created.

There is an interesting discussion in github about the way to transition support of these 2 functions in cleos. https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/7536

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!